# Image not displayed in IE 11.But working in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

In IE 11
when https://localhost:8070/resource/6fbe89333dbd691683c1a781f6ccb828f32f433c/0/S.jpg
I am able to see the image

But when I put this into html

src of img tag in html

The image is not displayed and showing 'X' on screen

Answer (score 0):

pretty hard not knowing the directory of the files , do you store it in a img folder?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the issue on my side and found that it is working fine on my side.

Test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="http://localhost/pineapple.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="150" height="150">

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Looks like you have some issue in your HTML code or issue with some IE settings.

1. Try to check and verify that the image path is correct and the image is available there.
2. Check that your HTML code is correct.
3. Check the console to see whether there is any error or warning.
4. Check the code using developer tools and see the image related code to find the issue.
5. If the issue persists then try to post your sample HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an issue with IE only if the actual image format is different than the extension of the file .

The issue happens only with local files, and if you just changed the extension of the image to the actual format eg: gif, it will work

assume `test.jpg` file is located beside the html file then

```html
<img src="test.jpg"/>
```

this will not work in IE

if you just change the extension to

```html
<img src="test.gif"/>
```

then it will work